# JSON - Avoid UNICODE conversion

Tags: php, json, unicode

Why is my string converted to UNICODE in JSON?

> http://example.com/test/test.php?MyComment=%C4%93

Saved in JSON as `{"MyComment":"\u0113 "}`

I want to be saved as `{"MyComment":"%C4%93"}`

PHP:

```
$MyComment = $_GET["MyComment"];

print_r($MyComment); //%C4%93

$results = array ( array(

    "MyComment" => $MyComment, 

    ));

$inp = file_get_contents('Test.json');
$arr = json_decode($inp);
$results = array_merge($results, $arr);

$fp_login = fopen('Test.json', w);
fwrite($fp_login, json_encode($results));
fclose($fp_login);
```

Comment: Which charset are used?

Comment: sorry added my code]

Comment: It is not really a problem. A JSON parser will automatically convert those escapes back to the right characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to have the **urlencoded** value, you have to replace this:

```
$MyComment = $_GET["MyComment"];
```

with this (updated due to the comments below):

```
$MyComment = urlencode( $_GET["MyComment"] );
```

For your **Swift** problem you should use :

```
$MyComment = rawurlencode( $_GET["MyComment"] );
```

The whitespace will be encoded as `%20` so you can decode it at the Swift side.

console output:

> Object {MyComment: "%C4%93"}

Comment: doing this the spaces are converted as +

Comment: {"MyComment":"%C3%A6+%C3%AA"}

Comment: the spaces are converted as + because this  for a valid **URL** try to read this: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php. What was you intention to save this urlencoded?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I guess the problem is that Swift only decodes the `%20`so you need to use `rawurlencode()`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass the constant JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE to avoid it.

$json = json_encode($data, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

Comment: thank you now I get {"MyComment":"ē"} thats a good one however, how can I actually get the percent encoding ?

Comment: You should iterate to each field and pass it through urlencode. Or you can urlencode the whole json, but is not a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

In php 5.4+, php's json_encode does have the JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE option for plain output. On older php versions, you can roll out your own JSON encoder that does not encode non-ASCII characters.